# React Native Linking doesn't open ussd code on iPhone 13

Tags: react-native

Looking for a way to send USSD with # sign to the Dialer. It works on every device except for iPhone 13.
Usage:

```
Linking.openURL("tel:#1#");
```

Answer (score 1):

From [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html):

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number. If your app receives URL strings from the user or an unknown source, you should also make sure that any special characters that might not be appropriate in a URL are escaped properly. For native apps, use the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method of NSString to escape characters, which returns a properly escaped version of your original string.

So perhaps try calling :

```
Linking.openURL(`tel:${encodeURIComponent('#1#')}`);
```